# How to remove ubuntu yakkety totally

Tags: 16.04, 16.10

I tried to update ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 16.10 yakkety version by using this [steps](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-to-ubuntu-16-10). But however while installing updates I just stopped that. Then I update again by `$ sudo apt-get update` and got this kind of result.

```
user@user-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for user: 
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [1,189 B]           
Get:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [916 B]         
Hit:4 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                    
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,448 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:7 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease [102 kB]   
Get:8 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 310 kB in 5s (57.9 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
```

Therefore I want to remove all of the things of ubuntu yakkety. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a very bad idea to cancel an release-upgrade!
You can edit the sources by using

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and you have to edit the sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
for the Google repository too.

My recommendation: Be your own friend and make a clean install of 16.04 !!

Answer (score 0):

From your post I'm assuming you stopped the upgrade process before it could complete. Also you don't mention if its a desktop or server version.

The "update" command simple checks the repositories for any update against the cache.

I'd suggest you run the commands as per the steps you followed and wait for the installation to complete. The upgrade process will take some time depending on the specs of the PC.

For desktop version of Ubuntu, you can do this:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade